# JTree does not display inside JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtree

I need to display account names for my program and I want to do this using JTree inside a JScrollPane.

Here is my code:

```
public void loadAccounts() {

    accountsRoot = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Accounts"); //create root

    accountsRoot.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Fred")); //add one element
                                                          //for testing
    accounts = new JTree(accountsRoot);

    accountsPane = new JScrollPane(accounts);

    accountsPane.add(accounts);  //don't think this is necessary
    canvas.add(accountsPane);
    accounts.setBounds(0, 0, accountsPane.getWidth(), accountsPane.getHeight());
    accountsPane.setBounds(460, 270, 240, 410);
    accounts.setVisible(true);
    accountsPane.setVisible(true);

}
```

Because I am not using a layout I set the bounds manually.

I can't seem to get it to show. I want to eventually end up loading the accounts from a while so I figure JTree would be pretty easy for that,

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). `accountsPane.setBounds(460, 270, 240, 410);`  This might be the cause of the problem. ***Use Layout-Managers.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
accountsPane = new JScrollPane(accounts);

accountsPane.add(accounts);  //don't think this is necessary
```

Not only is that not necessary but it will mess things up as this in effect adds your accounts JTree to multiple containers -- to the JScrollPane's viewport (good) and to the JScrollPane itself (bad). Don't do that. Add it to the JScrollPane's viewport only either through the JScrollPane's constructor as shown on the first line above, or by calling `setViewportView(...)` on the JScrollPane object after creating it.

Edit: another problem is your use of `setBounds(...)`. You shouldn't be doing this but rather should be using layout managers to allow the proper viewing of your components. You will also need to call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on whatever container is accepting the JScrollPane.

Comment: Even without that second line I don't see the JTree being displayed. I should see at least two elements, the root and the child, no?

Comment: @F.Ali: see edit to answer. For more help, consider posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Is it possible to use a layout manager for one component inside an encompassing component that uses no layout manager? revalidate() and repaint() show the JTree but now the JScrollPane is hovering in the middle center of the JPanel.

Comment: @F.Ali: You need to study and learn to use the layout managers, period and end of story. It will all be explained in the tutorials.